# Apache Flink：Operator State Checkpoint

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to use the `Operator State API` in `No-Keyed Stream` to save the sate of `count` in the example below. what should I do?

```
public static class MapFunction implements MapFunction<String, String>,CheckpointedFunction{
    int count = 0;
    @Override
    public String map(String value) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String message;
            message = value;
            count++;
            return message;
    }

    @Override
    public void snapshotState(FunctionSnapshotContext context) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void initializeState(FunctionInitializationContext context) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I would suggest reading the docs: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/stream/state/state.html#working-with-state

Answer (score 1):

As Dawid noted, the docs are a good starting point. The easiest approach would be for you to implement the [ListCheckpointed](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#listcheckpointed) interface. When `snapshotState()` is called, you'd return a singleton list of your `count` (as an `Integer`). When `restoreState()` is called, you'd iterate over the list of `Integer` values, and sum them to set your `count` variable.